# Position of the word "being"

Tags: word-order

In the following sentence:

> This is the setting where such a phenomenon appears, being ((example)) a first important example.

Is the position of the word "being" correct? Is the following alternative better?

> This is the setting where such a phenomenon appears, ((example)) being a first important example.

Comment: Are you married to using *being*? It can make the language sound stiff, being of an older style.

Answer (score 1):

The standard word order in English is [Subject-Verb-Object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject%E2%80%93verb%E2%80%93object_word_order) (SVO). The fact that your clause containing *being* is non-finite, does not change that. Therefore, if we name the subject of *being* 'X':

> This is the setting where such a phenomenon appears, X *being* a first important example.

is the right order. If it weren't non-finite, your clause would be:

> ***X is*** (not is X) a first important example of this phenomenon.

Comment: 'An early' sounds more likely than 'a first'.